# Duplicate rows based on other columns containing values, then return row with split column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, strsplit

I have this df that contains rows that need to be duplicated based on number of letters split by '-' in 'Group' column.  I want each duplicated row to only contain a single letter from the 'Group' column .
XYZ does not have any "-" and would remain as a single non duplicated row.
Beginning df:

```
Date    End Time    Group   Assignment
2/2/2021    1130    A-B-C   quiz
2/2/2021    1230    XYZ     test
1/22/2021   1330    B-D     paper
1/22/2021   1130    A-E-C   homework
```

I have made several attempts at this, but can't get it.  Here is one example of what I tried:

```
df[['Group_1', 'Group_2', 'Group_3']] = df['Group'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df.drop(columns=['Group'], inplace=True)
df.to_csv('baz_schedule_modified.csv', index=False)

reps = [2 if not (val is np.nan) else 1 for val in df['Group_2']]  
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, reps)]
```

But I did not know where to go from there.

I am wanting the df to end up as follows:

```
Date    End Time    Group_1 Assignment
1/22/2021   1130    A   homework
1/22/2021   1330    B   paper
1/22/2021   1130    C   homework
1/22/2021   1330    D   paper
1/22/2021   1130    E   homework
2/2/2021    1130    A   quiz
2/2/2021    1130    B   quiz
2/2/2021    1130    C   quiz
2/2/2021    1230    XYZ test
```

Thank you for your help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.assign(Group=df['Group'].str.split('-')).explode('Group')
```

Output:

```
        Date  End Time Group Assignment
0   2/2/2021      1130     A       quiz
0   2/2/2021      1130     B       quiz
0   2/2/2021      1130     C       quiz
1   2/2/2021      1230   XYZ       test
2  1/22/2021      1330     B      paper
2  1/22/2021      1330     D      paper
3  1/22/2021      1130     A   homework
3  1/22/2021      1130     E   homework
3  1/22/2021      1130     C   homework
```

Using `assign` we can reassign `Group` as a list of strings delimited by '-' using str accessor and `split`.  Then using `pd.DataFrame.explode` we can explode that list to create the rows in the dataframe for each element in the list.

Comment: can you explain why "df['Group'] = df['Group'].str.split('-').explode('Group')" wont work but the assign will do the trick? Thanks

Comment: You are using `pd.Series.explode` instead of `pd.DataFrame.explode`.  When you use df[colname], you are creating a Series.  You can use explode but you are not expanding the dataframe.  so you are trying to set a dataframe column to a pd.Series longer than the dataframe.

Comment: ohh. Right. Thanks!